# Can two models reference each other by ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    default_contact = models.ForeignKey("CustomerContact", verbose_name="...", related_name="default_contacts", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    etc.
```

And

```
class CustomerContact(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='contacts')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_contacts', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    address = models.ForeignKey(CustomerAddress, ....)
```

In this example **Customer** points to **CustomerContact**.
At the same time **CustomerContact** points to **Customer**.

My coworker says that pointing **Customer** points to **CustomerContact** violates the OneToMany nature of `ForeignKey`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can add a flag **is_default_contact** in **CustomerContact** model and remove **default_contact** field from **Customer** model.

Comment: For sure, I agree with you. However,  that seems more onerous to the user managing the account.
I think `Customer.default_contact` is easier to manage from a UI perspective than going into a` CustomerContact` object and checking/unchecking for `is_default_contact`. Worth considering again, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you want to have many `CustomerContact` related to one `Customer`, but `Customer` can also pick his favourite (or one can be set by manager). It's valid approach.

It can go both ways, as long as you will secure `related_name`s properly.

```
default_contact = models.ForeignKey("CustomerContact", ... related_name="default_contacts") <= should be changed
```

`default_contacts` should be changed (i.e. to `default_for_customers`) because this name is for reversed relation, so actually for `CustomerContact`. It means, that you can use it in the following situation:

```
cc = CustomerContact.objects.get(id=1)
cc.default_for_customers.all()  <= this will return QuerySet of Customer objects that is default for
```

It's simplier and less confusing.

Comment: Yes, exactly.
The account managers set the customer contact that they deal with frequently.
This way, when an order is created for a given `Customer` the `CustomerContact` (via `default_contact` is populated automatically on the order)